# Content for the uri cannot be loaded

Tags: silverlight, navigation, uri

I tried to add a hyperlink in mainpage.xaml that goes on the student.xaml page.
student/xaml page is situated in view/student/
For the About Page is working and for Student Page doesn't want to

Code for hyperlinkbutton:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link2" Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
                                     NavigateUri="/About" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="{Binding Path=Strings.AboutPageTitle, Source={StaticResource ApplicationResources}}"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="Divider2" Style="{StaticResource DividerStyle}"/>

            <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link3" Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
                                     NavigateUri="Views/Student" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="{Binding Path=Strings.StudentPageTitle, Source={StaticResource ApplicationResources}}"/>
```

Code for uri mapping:

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}" 
                              Source="/Home" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed">
                <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
                  <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                    <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml"/>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                        <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Student/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/Student/{pageName}.xaml"/>
                    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
                </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
            </navigation:Frame>
```

and

```
private void ContentFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (UIElement child in LinksStackPanel.Children)
    {
        HyperlinkButton hb = child as HyperlinkButton;
        if (hb != null && hb.NavigateUri != null)
        {
            if (hb.NavigateUri.ToString().Equals(e.Uri.ToString()))
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "ActiveLink", true);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "InactiveLink", true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got `NavigateUri="Views/Student"` rather than `NavigateUri="/Views/Student"`. I hesitate to suggest that this is the problem, but it would be worth making things consistent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you've forgotten a "/" in your "Link3"-Hyperlink.
You should replace NavigateUri="Views/Student" with NavigateUri="/Views/Student"

**BUT:** 
 All in all your UriMapping looks a bit strange to me.
If you click on your About-Hyperlink it will use the mapping Uri="/{pageName}" and navigate to "/Views/About.xaml"

--> If you want to Navigate to your Students.xaml you should use **NavigateUri="/Student"** only which will end up navigating to "/Views/Student.xaml"

Hope that helps ;)